# Trying to set and use environment variables with PHP on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, environment-variables

I am trying to set and use environment variable on my ubuntu 14.04 box with PHP.

I tried the following:

edited /etc/apache/envvars file, and added the following:

```
export MY_TEST=/home/myfolder/
```

And added the following line to /etc/apache2.conf:

```
PassEnv MY_TEST
```

Then I wrote a test script:

```
<?php
echo getenv('MY_TEST');
```

I restarted Apache2:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and then I did:

```
php mytest.php
```

Nothing.

I then tried editing the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file by adding:

```
SetEnv MY_TEST="/home/myfolder/"
```

I restarted the Apache2 server, and then ran the script. Nothing. What am I doing wrong?